# List all running EC2 instances without any snapshots

Tags: amazon-web-services

Does anyone know of an AWS CLI command that will list any running instance (run against a particular region) that doesn't have a snapshot available.

The closest command Ive found to try would be something like:

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --owner-ids self  --query 'Snapshots[]' --region=us-east-1
```

I didn't actually get any return on it - just:

```
-------------------
|DescribeSnapshots|
+-----------------+
```

This is supposed to name every EC2 snapshot for each instance -- so I would have to subtract these ones from the entire EC2 inventory to reveal EC2 instances without.

Hence - I would like a command that would show running EC2 instances without any snapshots available -- so I can put something in place going forward.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon EBS Snapshots are associated with Amazon EBS Volumes, which are associated with Amazon EC2 instances.

Therefore, you would need to write a program using an AWS SDK (I'd use Python, but there are many available) that would:

- Obtain a list of all **EBS Snapshots** (make sure you use the equivalent to `--owner-ids self`), in which the return data will include the associated EBS `VolumeId`
- Obtain a list of all **EBS Volumes**, in which the return data will include `Attachments.InstanceId`
- Obtain a list of all running **EC2 instances**

Do a bit of looping logic to find Volumes without Snapshots, and then determine which instances are associated to those Volumes.

Note that rather than finding *"instances without snapshots"* it has to find *"instances that have volumes without snapshots"*.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is by default a CLI command that will allow you to do this. You can tag your snapshots with your instance ids for example then can query snapshots by filtering on the tags. Or you will have to use AWS SDK and create a custom script to allow you the get all instances and then check their volume ids if they have snapshots created or not.

Comment: Think the best way forward might be going with AWS SDK route like boto3 for that.