# Using Boto3 to check the last time a snapshot was taken for a list of given volumes

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

Currently I have a script that creates a list of all volumes that are attached to a given instance. I would like to iterate through this list of volumes, checking the status and date for the last snapshot of each volume.

How would I go about doing this? I have included my code so far.

Thanks in advance for any advise

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
instance = ec2.Instance('instance1')

volumes = instance.volumes.all()
listVolumes = []
for v in volumes:
    listVolumes.append(v.id)

print(listVolumes)
```

Comment: Might be helpful: [List all running EC2 instances without any snapshots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68809910/174777)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to:

- Obtain a list of **EBS volumes** (as you have done)
- Obtain a list of **EBS snapshots** in your AWS Account (use owner-ids = self)
- Loop through the snapshots, looking at the `volume_id` to associate it to an EBS volume
- Do some clever coding to figure out the latest snapshot (eg use a dictionary and a bit of sorting)

By the way, you can use `volumes_list = list(instance.volumes.all())`

If you have trouble with the code, feel free to update your question and ask for help.